# 5 Days Notice from Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6007147#ts=3049653

This warning came to me.

What should I do?

Comment: The page you linked clearly says "If you find any existing applications in your catalog to be in non-compliance, we ask you to remedy or unpublish the app from Play within 15 calendar days of this notification. After this time period, applications discovered to be in violation may be subject to removal from Google Play." So, read the new policy and make sure your apps adhere to the policy. If all is well there's nothing you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html
2. Check you apps, if any existing applications in your catalog violate content policy, unpublish the app
3. If you don't have any apps that seems violate, nothing happen..

Answer (score 0):

This is sent to all developers when Google changes their developer policy. If your apps are in compliance with the new policy you do not need to do anything. Otherwise, you have 15 days to publish a new compliant version of your app.